# Trigger same Glue Job with Different Parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a Glue job which I want to execute twice each time with few parameters changing. Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible.
You can Create one lambda which will generate one output which has 2 sets of parameter for each run as per requirement.
Setup the Step-Function, in that step function you can pass the JSON i.e the output of Lambda to Glue job as input-parameter